# Unable to install php-5 phalcon for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, phalcon

My machine is running on ubuntu 16.04 and I have installed php 5.6, but when I am trying to run to install php5-phalcon, it returns error that package not found.

Following is command that I ran

```
sudo apt-get install php5-phalcon
```

It returns following output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5-phalcon
```

Comment: https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/6217/ubuntu-cant-install-phalcon

Comment: Try with `sudo apt-get install php5.6-phalcon` or what ever minor version your PHP is.

Comment: that's not possible, minimum version supported is 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying few methods, found that php5.6-phalcon is not available for ubuntu 16.04, following are steps to install php7.0-phalcon :

```
curl -s "https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh" | sudo bash

# Ubuntu 16.04+, Debian 9+
sudo apt-get install php7.0-phalcon
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the correct repository in first...

```
curl -s "https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh" | sudo bash

sudo apt-get install php5-phalcon

# Ubuntu 16.04+, Debian 9+
sudo apt-get install php7.0-phalcon
```

(From https://phalconphp.com/en/download/linux)

Comment: I tried, but that wasn't working maybe because php5-phalcon is not available for ubuntu 16.04, hence moved my php version to 7+.

Comment: Sorry - I've added the next few lines from the page, your right 5 isn't available, but php7.0-phalcon is.